# Can OpenVAS do a scan on a scanner device?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, vulnerability-assessment, vulnerability-management, openvas

I know OpenVAS can scan printers with just tweaking some scan configuration.
I try to scan a scanner device but I only get one result which is OS Detection Consolidation and Reporting.

I have an Epson Scanner for reference.
Are there any settings that I should change?

Can't find any info about this. Is it necessary to scan scanners?

Comment: What do you mean by "scanners"? Document scanners scanning other vulnerability scanners?

Comment: @schroeder Hi! What I mean by scanners are document/image scanners. For example an Epson Perfection V39 Scanner.